# htaccess rewrite rule to clanek.php?odkaz=pagename

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

My link looks like this:

```
<a href="clanek.php?odkaz=The-Emerald-Nightmare-prehled">The Emerald Nightmare - přehled</a>
```

(http://icyveins.cz/clanek.php?odkaz=The-Emerald-Nightmare-prehled)

But I'd like this:
http://icyveins.cz/clanek/The-Emerald-Nightmare-prehled

in .htaccess I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /clanek.php?odkaz=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it does not work. You advise me please, how do I edit my links (`<a href>`) and .htaccess and make it work?

Thank You!!

Comment: You're missing the `/clanek/` in your rule for one then you're only allowing alphanumerical characters

Comment: Could you write to me? Much please

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**

Format link `<a href="The-Emerald-Nightmare-prehled">The Emerald Nightmare - přehled</a>`

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ clanek.php?odkaz=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**RESULT**

```
http://icyveins.cz/The-Emerald-Nightmare-prehled
```

^^